# Function returns signature but not the string

Tags: javascript

I asked a question about an hour and got it figured out, then another issue arised.. I am getting back the signature of the function and not the string that is passed to it. However if I add a console.log to the function it shows me the object..

Here is the code that I am using

```
var UsableObjects = {
    Person: function (a, b) {
        var self = this;
        var person = {
            FirstName: a,
            LastName: b
        };
        self.ShowMyPerson(person);
    },
    ShowMyPerson: function (mystring) {
        console.log(mystring);
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

I am passing the values to the Person like so

```
UsableObjects.Person("Joe", "Smith");
```

Thats working, however when I call ShowMyPerson, I see the object in the console, and it looks like this

```
Object {FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith"}
```

but when I call it like this

```
var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson;
console.log(abc);
```

I get this returned

```
function (mystring) {
    console.log(mystring);
    return mystring;
}
```

and if I try this

```
console.log(abc.FirstName);
```

I get an undefined in the console..

What I'm expecting to get returned is this..

```
{FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith"}
```

So the question is, why am I not getting my expected results?

Comment: abc is function not object

Comment: UsableObjects is a object with property ShowMyPerson refering to a anonymous function, so if you log the value of ShowMyPerson , it will log the function. You need to use `()` to invoke the function

Comment: yes because UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson is a function and also when you call itn it needs an argument that will be logged. So this way var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson; abc will also become a function instead try var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson(); it will return undefined as you are not passing any argumnet.

Comment: I made a comment on the answer..So it seems that the ShowMyPerson is the issue and shouldn't be a function. From the answers I am seeing make UsableObjects.Person useless because it does the same thing as UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson, other than returning the object. What I want to do is pass the values to UsableObjects.Person and use the UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson to return the object. How do I change the ShowMyPerson from a function to just to return the object or how to get the ShowMyPerson function to return an object that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing

```
var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson;
```

you are not calling the ShowMyPerson function, you are just making your variable abc to refer to that function.

To call it you need to use () after the function name, like

```
var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson();
```

Also note that your function wants an argument as parameter to it, so pass an arguments also.

For example

```
var abc = UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson({FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith"});
```

The function ShowMyPerson returns whatever is passed as argument to it, so in this case abc will now be an object with keys FirstName and LastName

Now you can access the values as

```
abc.FirstName
```

Here is a working example of your requirement

https://jsfiddle.net/f875c7t5/1/

```
var UsableObjects = {
    Person: function (a, b) {
        var self = this;
        var person = {
            FirstName: a,
            LastName: b
        };
        self.ShowMyPerson=person;
        return this;
    },
    ShowMyPerson:''
}

var abc = UsableObjects.Person("d","f");

console.log(abc.ShowMyPerson.FirstName);
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to change the ShowMyPerson from a function then because if I have to pass it those arguements then the UsableObjects.Person function is pointless to use

Comment: I see where you are going with this, and you are correct. Maybe I should explain a little more... Just say I have 3 scripts, script A contains the functions in question...Script b creates the Person by UsableObjects.Person("Joe", "Smith"); That data stays there and is not necessarily going to called again from Script b..So Script c comes along and wants the data sitting in the Person object, so Script c calls the ShowMyPerson without passing any values to it and just wants the ShowMyPerson to be returned as an object so its values can be accessed

Comment: Sorry I had copy pasted a wrong line from fiddle, Now check the code,  I think it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `ShowMyPerson` as method but instead trying to access it as property. Correct way to call the method (note that it accepts parameter) would be

```
UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson({FirstName: 'Joe', LastName: 'Smith'})
```

```js
var UsableObjects = {
    Person: function (a, b) {
        var self = this;
        var person = {
            FirstName: a,
            LastName: b
        };
        self.ShowMyPerson(person);
    },
    ShowMyPerson: function (mystring) {
        console.log(mystring);
        return mystring;
    }
}
function callMe()
{
 var abc =  UsableObjects.ShowMyPerson({FirstName: 'Joe', LastName: 'Smith'});
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = abc.FirstName;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="javascript:callMe();"/>
<div id="result">

</div>
```